# how can implement Extended Floating Action Button in android

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, androidx

So many references explain about [extended-floating-action-button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/)

with [Material Components libarary](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

for use this feature must merge android studio with **androidx** and add

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

library >= 4 and must put extended-floating-action-button in CooordinatoriLayout

i do everything right and past from so many issues like

```
The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

but fixed with changing parent style with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

now i see extended-floating-action-button in layout correctly 
[image]

but still cant use implement Extended Floating Action Button 
and when run project 
got this error 
`Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton`

with description  `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`

i do so many research about this but there is no good and complete reference or tutorial and i am wonder any one in the world could use this feature ?

[this is what i want](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1OTb9HPdZYx_7NVc3cizpA0T4ItMRb9Xi%2Fefab-scroll.mp4)

> UPDATED
>
> problem came from parent layout! android:theme="@style/AppTheme" must
>   be added in parent layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the appcompat theme in your layout with styles.xml like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

change it to these lines

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
```

after that, you import that style in your layout

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"//here is the xml layout root tag>
```

Sorry I Forgot the main thing

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

you also have to do this.
and don't use appcompat and material theme in the same layout, please

Comment: still same problem

Comment: problem came from parent layout!   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  must be added in parent layout